# GCP Dataflow vCPU usage and pricing question

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I submited a GCP dataflow pipeline to receive my data from GCP Pub/Sub, parse and store to GCP Datastore. It seems work perfect.

Through 21 days, I found the cost is $144.54 and worked time is 2,094.72 hour. It means after I submitted it, it will be charged every sec, even there is not receive (process) any data from Pub/Sub.

Is this behavior normal? Or I set a wrong parameters?
I thought CPU use time only be counted when data is received.

Is there have any way to reduce the cost in same working model (receive from Pub/Sub and store to Datastore)?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong of my question, why downvote it.. Please give me some comment or message, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cloud Dataflow service [usage is billed](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#pricing_overview) in per second increments, on a per job basis. I guess your job used 4 n1-standard-1 workers, which used 4 vCPUs giving an estimated of 2,000 vCPU hr [resource usage](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#workers_and_worker_resources). Therefore, this behavior is normal. To reduce the cost, you can use either [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling), to specify the maximum number of workers, or the [pipeline options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options), to override the resource settings that are allocated to each worker. Depending on your necessities, you could consider using [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview#functions) which [cost less](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#top_of_page), but considering its [limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#top_of_page).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explain, I am grateful. Let me make sure I have it right, Dataflow is charged when a job "start", even it is no handle/receive any data. The only way to reduce the cost is to reduce the resource allocated, even there is not any data incoming, the usage time is still increment every seconds. Am I understand correct? Thanks again.

Comment: That's right. Since you start using the resources regardless of your data handling.